# Has PyDev an interactive shell (during debugging) as in Komodo?

Tags: python, pydev

so far I used the Komodo IDE for Python development, but I'm now testing Eclipse with PyDev. Everything works fine, but there is one Komodo feature that I'm missing.
In Komodo I can inspect the running application in a debugger shell. I.e. after hitting a breakpoint I can not only read the content of variables, but I can execute arbitrary Python code (e.g. changing the value of variables) and then continue program execution.
PyDev has also some interactive shell during debugging, but I can only read variables and not change their content. Is this feature not available in PyDev or am I missing something here?

Many thanks,
 Axel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do that.  Just type in the console what ever commands you want :). I usually have to right click then

> Debug As >> Python run

PyDev is a little bit quirky, but you get used to it.

Comment: Indeed it works !  When I tried that earlier I was confused because the variable content was not immediately updated in the variables panel, but as soon as I do a further single step with the debugger, the GUI is updated. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As you've seen, you can just use the console directly:

http://pydev.org/manual_adv_debug_console.html

Now, you can also connect the interactive console (which is a bit more advanced) by selecting a stack frame to attach it:

http://pydev.org/manual_adv_interactive_console.html